# Find and replace in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

I'm attempting to find and replace `\$GET['[^']+']` with `($0)` but it literally replaces with `($0)` rather than `($GET[''])`

Regex mode is active.

How can I search and replace using the results of the search in the replace?

Comment: No, it's actually not. But I did find a solution and will post shortly

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that `\$GET['[^']+']` doesn't have a capture group, and the first returned string is $1 not $0.

- Find `(\$GET['[^']+'])`
- Replace `($1)`

Works as expected